# Jenkins Build Blocker plugin

Tags: jenkins, build

I am using jenkins build blocker plugin to perform a below scenario:

1. I have a main job A which gets executed and then as a post build step I trigger Job B which reverts my VM back.
2. When job B is executing, I have configured Job A to get block until job B is finished. Meanwhile if any new requests comes up, then it gets queued for Job A.

The problem I am facing is that, the job remains in the queue even when Job B is finished and slave is idle to run Job A. Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Can you post the output of `<your_server_url:port>/queue/api/json?pretty=true`, and maybe a screenshot of how you've set up your build to block?

Comment: Do your jobs have labels? Just a wild guess but you might be hit by https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-blocker-plugin/pull/9